# JSON TSQL add element in middle of array

Tags: arrays, json, t-sql

I have the following:

```
declare @X nvarchar(max)
set @X='[
            {
              "a": "",
              "b": "",
              "c": "",              
              "e": "",
              "f": "",
              "g": ""
            }
        ]'
declare @y nvarchar(max)
set @y='{"bac": ""}'
```

And this is what I need:

```
'"pro": [
            {
              "a": "",
              "b": "",
              "c": "",
              "address": {
                  "bac": ""
              },
              "e": "",
              "f": "",
              "g": ""
            }
        ]'
```

Comment: Poorly formatted requirements dumps are not attractive to researchers or answerers. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: A very simple suggestion: use `REPLACE()` to replace `"e":` with `"address":{"bac":""},"e":`. You can do the same with `"c":` of course - or both...

Comment: only JSON related TSQL functions can be used